# Display Spinner till API Response in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new to Angular 6 and no experience in any version of angular previously & creating my website using angular 6, in which i have to display spinner till API Response is pending.I am using **httpclient** of angular 6 to call APIs. I want to show spinner for every API request. I searched on SO but didn't find answer of my question.Below is my component & services file.

```
/* data.services.ts */

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  } 
}

/* users.component.ts *

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
 })

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users$: Object;
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users$ = data; 
    });
  }
}
```

**Note: I don't want to use any package or module for that.**

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you insist on not installing any packages then use a boolean flag to tell if the loading has finished yet

Get a loading animation from https://loading.io/ to put in the loading section of the html

```
/* data.services.ts */

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  } 
}

/* users.component.ts *

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
 })

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: Object; // <-- Do not use $ at the end of a variable unless it is an observable
  loading = true;
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
}

<div *ngIf="loading else loaded">
    loading ...
</div>

<ng-template #loaded>
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: @Rajat Perhaps this is what you are looking for

Comment: and what is the ng-template above?

Comment: the div with the ngIf is where you put your loading spinner, the ng-template is where you put your users, it is what is shown when the loading flag goes from true to false

Comment: One more question, can i use simple approach instead of ng-template?

Comment: <div *ngIf="loading">show spinner here</div> <div *ngIf="!loading">show users here</div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180156/discussion-between-rajat-and-adrian-brand).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ng4-loading-spinner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-loading-spinner)

Execute `npm i ng4-loading-spinner --save`

Import module to your application root module

```
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
```

Make an import entry

```
 imports: [ Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot() ]
```

Include spinner component to your root level component.

```
<ng4-loading-spinner> </ng4-loading-spinner>
```

use `show()` and `hide()` inside `subscribe` callback

```
   import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
     constructor(
            private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService,
            private data: DataService
        ) { }
       ngOnInit() {
         this.spinnerService.show();//show the spinner
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users$ = data; 
       this.spinnerService.hide();//hide the spinner if success
    },
    (error)=>this.spinnerService.hide();//hide the spinner in case of error
 );
  }}
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng4-loading-spinner)**

Comment: I dont' want to use any module for that. I only want simple approach.

Comment: Angular does not have in-built spinner either u can use spinner from front-awesome or use angular's material [mat-spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview) or use the one provided in the answers else  Good luck with creating your custom spinner   :)

Comment: @Viaks I have a gif image. I just want the logic.

Comment: then it's easy use `*ngIf` to conditionally show and hide the spinner

Comment: can you please edit my code. I don't know the basic functionality of angular.

Answer (score 2):

For that purpose I would use http interceptor for checking certain events during http request.
Let's have component which will have some loader and put that component on same level like router outlet or app component.
From our interceptor we will communicate with service to tell our component whenever show loader or not.

There is simple angular 6 example for that:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgxcsu

Answer (score 1):

You could store a reference on the subscription as a users component property, then use a simple *ngIf in your template to show/hide the loading indicator :

```
/* users.component.ts *

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users$: Object;
  subscription: Subscription

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users$ = data; 
    });
  }
}
```

In your template:

```
...
<div *ngIf="!subscription?.closed">loading...</div>
...
```

See http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html for more infos on Subscription class.

It's beyond this question scope but you also should check that your subscription is closed when your component is destroyed (so keeping a reference on the subscription can help): call subscription.unsubscribe() if necessary in ngOnDestroy() for example, or extend from a base class for this purpose (so all of your components could benefit from it).

See https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/ or https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my package ngx-RxCache. Dealing with loading is one of the key use cases. Install ngx-rxcache. Don't subscribe to observables in your TypeScript, use the async pipe in your view. Check out a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3yqpfe

Get a loading animation from https://loading.io/ to put in the loading section of the html

```
/* data.services.ts */

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RxCacheService } from 'ngx-rxcache';
import { User } from 'path to user interface definition';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cache: RxCacheService) { }
  load() {
    this.usersCacheItem.load();
  }

  private usersCacheItem = this.cache.get<User[]>({
      id: '[User] users',
      construct: () => this.http.get<User[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    });

    users$ = this.usersCacheItem.value$;
    loading$ = this.usersCacheItem.loading$;
}

/* users.component.ts *

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
 })

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users$: this.data.users$;
  loading$: this.data.loading$;
  constructor(private data: DataService) {
    data.load();
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="loading$ | async; else loaded">
    loading ...
</div>

<ng-template #loaded>
    <div *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">{{item}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I dont' want to use any module for that. I only want simple approach.

Comment: Using ngx-RxCache is about as simple as it gets. Hand rolling your own solution is not the simple approach. Why would you be opposed to installing a module? Having a module that deals with your state management for you will increase your productivity greatly.

Comment: It is because i just want to understand the basic functionality of angular 6 before going on advance topics.